# How do i login to azure SQL using users identity from a ASP.Net application

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have a ASP.Net application that uses Azure AD Authentication, howver i want to connect to the azure database using the loggedin users identity. "Active Directory Integrated is not working for this scenario.

When a user logs into my application using microsoft login page, the same user should be able to login ( not the application identity) to the database and perform some execution.

Comment: How can i get a token for database based on the logged in user if i want to use Token based authentication to the azure sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer the code below:

```
public async Task<string> GetTokenForApplicationAsync()
        {
            string signedInUserID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            string tenantID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
            string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

            // get a token for the Graph without triggering any user interaction (from the cache, via multi-resource refresh token, etc)
            ClientCredential clientcred = new ClientCredential(Startup.ClientId, Startup.AppKey);

            // initialize AuthenticationContext with the token cache of the currently signed in user, as kept in the token cache
            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(Startup.AadInstance + tenantID, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync("https://database.windows.net/", clientcred, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
            return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
        }
```

Here is an [webapp sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect) which integrate with Azure AD and get access token for calling Microsoft Graph API. Just replace the GraphResourceId with `https://database.windows.net/`.